# Why is $(12)(34).3 = 4?$

Tags: group-theory, group-actions

[Source](https://www.math.utah.edu/%7Eschwede/math435/GroupSetNotes.pdf) Page No $1$.

Suppose that $G = S_4$, the group of permutations on the set $S = \{1, 2, 3, 4\}$. We
illustrate the action of $G$ on $S$ as in the following examples:

$$(12)(34).3 = 4.$$

**My confusion**: why is $$(12)(34).3 = 4?$$

**My thinking**: Here  $(12)(34).(3)=\begin{pmatrix} 1&2&3&4 \\2 &1&4&3 \end{pmatrix}(3)=(12)(34)$

Maybe I'm wrong.

Here $3$ is only one cycle. How can we apply the product of permutation?

Note: I know the rule of  product of permutation for example I can calculate $(1324)(243)=142$

Comment: $(12)(34).3$ means that you apply the permutation $(12)(34)$ to the element $3$, and not that you compose $(12)(34)$ with the permutation $(3)$ (which has not a lot of sense, btw).

Comment: By definition of your source, first $(12)$ is applied to $3$, which leaves it unchanged. Then $(34)$ is applied, which maps $3$ to $4$. So it seems correct. Anyway here, disjoint permutations commute, so the order is irrelevant.

Comment: Your notation is not clear, but the action of the group element on the element $3\in S$ is to send it to the element $4\in S$. This may be what is meant, but until you explain the notation it is hard to be sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes,

$$\begin{align}
(12)(34).3&=(12)(34)3\\
&=4.
\end{align}$$

This can be seen by splitting $(12)(34)$ into its two components: $f:=(12)$ and $g:=(34)$. Then

$$3\xrightarrow{g}4\xrightarrow{f}4.$$

---

Your confusion is in thinking $3$ is a one-cycle; rather, it is an *argument* of the function $f\circ g=(12)(34)$.

---

By the way,

$$(1324)(243)=(1342).$$